# Session state availability for background worker threads in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to kick off a background worker thread from a client AJAX request.  So the request returns immediately and the background thread handles the processing.  Is Session state available to this background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - if your background thread is running in the same AppDomain as an ASP.NET site. `HttpContext.Current.Session` will get you access to it. Ignoring of course an entire topic of how to best handle multi-threading in web apps, how to best handle injecting dependencies into your backend code (whether a controller or some other technology du jour) for testability, this will get you there quickest and dirtiest.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I am writing this answer, session is not available in a thread other that the one that is processing the current requrest.
If there is not any request, *Current* property of *HttpContext* is null.
But if in that background thread, you are using *session* after a request received, it is available while the request is alive and has been not completed.
There may be a better solution for you requirement.
Any way if you must use background thread, accessing the session is not the only problem that you are encountering. You should consider fault situations that may happen for you thread and be careful that your application does not go to inappropriate state. For example IIS may recycle AppDomain ( although this one almost can be handled by HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject )